# android modules - How do I make a variable acessible only inside the module and not outside?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently building an Android Studio module structured like the following:

```
com.example.module
+--- .activity
+--- .adapter
+--- .fragment
+--- etc. package names
+--- .view
+--- InterfaceClass.java
```

I intend to make the InterfaceClass.java to be the 'gateway of access' into the module itself. It's structured roughly like this:

```
public class InterfaceClass
{
    private static InterfaceClass instance;
    private static AppCompatActivity starterAct;
    public static int sDisplayWidth, sDisplayHeight;

    public static InterfaceClass getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (InterfaceClass.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new InterfaceClass();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setup(AppCompatActivity starterAct) {
        this.starterAct = starterAct;
        this.updateScreenSize()
    }

    ...

    private void updateScreenSize() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.starterAct.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        sDisplayWidth = size.x;
        sDisplayHeight = size.y;
    }
}
```

My intention is to make the variables `sDisplayWidth` and `sDisplayHeight` accessible only inside the `com.example.module` module and all its packages, not outside the module. Because with the current setup I can just call or set `InterfaceClass.sDisplayWidth` from anywhere, even in the activity of the app using the module, and I want it to only be set up in the instance's setup code, and usable only within the module.

I don't think the `protected` modifier works either, because it ends up not being accessible inside the packages of the module.

My question: How exactly do I make the variable accessible only within the module?

EDIT: To clarify, instead of the variable being `package-private`, I want it to be `module-private`.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the question but are you asking for how to make a variable package-private?  If you are, just remove the public modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible right now. The new [module system](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/java-9-new-features) feature has been announced in Java 9 and it might come to Android sooner or later.

The closest modifier is `package-private` but it doesn't grant the visibility to the nested packages.

Comment: So until Java 9 is adapted for Android, it's not possible to make it module-private?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Believe me, I'm struggling as well :( The only thing you can do - organize your packages in a way that `package-private` access will serve you in a best way

Answer (score 0):

Removing access specifier will make it `package-private`. Try it out.

```
 static int sDisplayWidth, sDisplayHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question perfectly you could try giving it `package-private` access that is, it will only be accessed by your module if it is residing in the root of the module and hence will not be accessible to classes outside the module

So try doing below to make it `package-private`

```
public class InterfaceClass {

 private static InterfaceClass instance;
 private static AppCompatActivity starterAct;
 static int sDisplayWidth, sDisplayHeight;

 public static InterfaceClass getInstance() {
     if (instance == null) {
         synchronized (InterfaceClass.class) {
             if (instance == null) {
                 instance = new InterfaceClass();
             }
         }
     }
     return instance;
 }

 public void setup(AppCompatActivity starterAct) {
     this.starterAct = starterAct;
     this.updateScreenSize()
 }

 ...

 private void updateScreenSize() {
     WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
       this.starterAct.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
     Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

     Point size = new Point();
     display.getSize(size);
     sDisplayWidth = size.x;
     sDisplayHeight = size.y;
 }
}
```

Comment: Here's the thing: when I try to access it from inside the `com.example.module.fragment` package, it fails to compile with the error message: "Cannot be accessed from outside package".

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337 Yeah it does not give access to the nested package